# Java Graphics2D - Image Watermark with Randomly Located Tag Cloud

Tags: java, random, graphics2d, watermark

I am trying to take an input image and watermark it with a text string in Java.
I have 2 versions of this program.

The first version iterates across the image horizontally and vertically using the font size as equal spacing.

The second version creates a list of Rectangle objects and checks if each rectangle added to the list intersects with the existing ones. If it does intersect then it randomly moves the Rectangle until it fits.

My problem is - the second version does not prevent overlapping text even though i am checking the list of existing rectangles using:
if(rectList.get(j).intersects(rect))

Can anyone help?

**Version 1**

```
/*
* Author: Hugh Pearse
* Purpose: watermark image
*/
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.Font;

public class Prog5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            int fontSize = 12;
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(args[0]));
            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();

            AlphaComposite ac = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, .3f);
            g.setComposite(ac);
            g.setFont(new Font( "SansSerif", Font.BOLD, fontSize ));
            g.setColor(Color.blue);

            String msg = "©Hugh Pearse";
            for(int i=1; i<=image.getHeight(); i=i+fontSize)
            for(int j=1; j<=image.getWidth(); j=j+(fontSize*msg.length()))
            g.drawString(msg, j, i);

            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File(args[0].toString().replace(".", "_watermarked.")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Version 2**

```
/*
 * Author: Hugh Pearse
 * Purpose: Randomly located watermark v3
 */
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.Font;

public class Image1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Random rand = new Random();

            //variables for controlling visual effect
            int fontSize = 40;
            String msg = "©Hugh Pearse";
            float msgOpacity = .1f;
            String typeface = "SansSerif";
            int style = Font.BOLD;
            Color msgColour = Color.blue;
            int numberOfWatermarks = 16;

            //image objects
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(args[0]));
            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();

            //apply settings for overlay
            AlphaComposite ac = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, msgOpacity);
            g.setComposite(ac);
            g.setColor(msgColour);

            List<Rectangle> rectList = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();

            for(int i=0; i<=numberOfWatermarks; i++){
                System.out.println("Attempting to draw rectangle " + i);

                //message Rectangle attributes
                Font msgFont = new Font( typeface, style, fontSize );
                g.setFont(msgFont);
                FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics(msgFont);
                int w = metrics.stringWidth(msg);
                int h = metrics.getHeight();
                int x = 0;
                int y = 0;
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);

                //randomly choose location for text
                rect.x = rand.nextInt(image.getHeight());
                rect.y = rand.nextInt(image.getWidth());

                if(rectList.size() == 0){
                    rectList.add(rect);
                    g.drawString(msg, rect.x, rect.y);
                }
                else{
                    //compare to every existing rectangle
                    for(int j=0; j<rectList.size(); j++){
                        //check if new rectangle intersects with existing rectangles
                        int attempts = 0;
                        while(attempts <= 100){
                            if (rectList.get(j).intersects(rect)){
                                //change rectangle location if intersects
                                rect.setLocation(rand.nextInt(image.getHeight()), rand.nextInt(image.getWidth()));
                                attempts++;
                            }
                            else{
                                rectList.add(rect);
                                g.drawString(msg, rect.x, rect.y);
                                attempts = 101;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File(args[0].toString().replace(".", "_watermarked.")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Here is an example of the images created by the programs (Origional, Random and 2d matrix):
http://imgur.com/a/StVT5

Comment: I added
`g.draw(rect);`
and it comes out like this: [imgur-link](http://i.imgur.com/TnaLM.jpg).
a quick fix is `g.drawString(msg, rect.x, rect.y+metrics.getAscent());` but does not solve the overlapping problem...
[imgur-link](http://imgur.com/jWvP6)