# Add a repeated text watermark to an image with Codename One

Tags: codenameone

Is it possible to add a repeated text as watermark to an Image using the Codename One API?

For example, giving an Image and a text of one or more words, I'd like to create a new Image like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure just use a mutable image:

```
Image watered = Image.create(sourceImg.getWidth(), sourceImg.getHeight());
Graphics g = watered.getGraphics();
g.drawImage(sourceImg, 0, 0);
g.setAlpha(30);
g.setColor(0xcccccc);
g.rotate(Math.PI / 2, sourceImg.getWidth() / 2, sourceImg.getHeight() / 2);


// here you can loop and do draw String a lot and just move with string width/height

// or you can use multiple drawImage calls and have a ready made watermark
// this might actually look better and won't require the alpha/rotation code
```

Answer (score 0):

I referred to the code in this answer ([Java Graphics2D - Image Watermark with Randomly Located Tag Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396631/java-graphics2d-image-watermark-with-randomly-located-tag-cloud)), modified it like this

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    addTextWatermark("Photopea",

            new File("E:\\sourceImageFile.jpg"),

            new File("E:\\destImageFile.jpg"));

}

static void addTextWatermark(String text, File sourceImageFile, File destImageFile) {

    try {
        int fontSize = 60;
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(sourceImageFile);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();

        AlphaComposite ac = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 1f);
        g.setComposite(ac);
        g.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.PLAIN, fontSize));
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.rotate(Math.PI / -10);

        final String[] splitStr = text.split("\n");
        int maxMsgLength = Arrays.stream(splitStr).mapToInt(String::length).max().orElse(0);

        final int enterTotal = splitStr.length;

        for (int i = -image.getHeight(); i <= image.getHeight() * 2; i = i + (fontSize * enterTotal + 200)) {
            for (int j = -image.getWidth(); j <= image.getWidth() * 2; j = j + (fontSize * maxMsgLength)) {
                for (int subIndex = 0; subIndex < splitStr.length; subIndex++) {
                    g.drawString(splitStr[subIndex], j, i + ((fontSize) * subIndex));
                }
            }
        }

        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", destImageFile);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I thank you, but your answer is not valid. The Codename One API (https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/) is different from the Java SE API (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/). The reason is explained in detail here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/why-we-dont-support-the-full-java-api.html. The article is a bit dated but overall still valid. The article mentions the exclusive use of Ant; today, Codename One uses Maven.